# Access named layouts of sObjects

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to test the [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_named_layouts.htm) to get named layouts of sObjects. In this case can you point me how to create a named layout for a custom object or to an sObject type which already has namedLayouts